Who plays the actor installing greenhouse in Petulia?
Here are two screen caps:


In the screenplay the character is described as "First Gentleman". George C. Scott comes home to find him and a colleague installing a portable greenhouse. Neither the credits of the film nor IMDb identifies the actor. At first I thought it was Richard Jenkins but it can't be, because this is a 1968 film and Jenkins didn't begin acting in films until 1974.

If he had a speaking part It would be very unusual for him not to be listed in the end credits somewhere. It's practically mandatory.

@Paulie_D in old Hollywood movies it was quite common for actors with small speaking roles not to be credited. In [i]Petulia[/i], for example, Rene Auberjonois and Howard Hesseman have minor speaking roles but are uncredited.

This appears to be character actor Richard Stahl.  His imdb page doesn't list him as appearing in Petulia though.  He guest starred in several sitcoms during the 1970's and 80's 

Thank you, @Legion600, it must be Richard Stahl. Petulia had members of the troupe [The Committee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Committee_(improv_group)] in various minor roles. I'm not sure whether it's from Five Easy Pieces that I recognized him, or from his sitcom appearances. He does kinid of resemble Richard Jenkins, for a moment I thought I had found an early appearance by Jenkins that nobody was aware of!
